# Find processes which have a file open without lsof or fuser

Tags: linux, files, lsof, fuser

I'm working on a Linux (Scientific Linux CERN SLC release 6.9 (Carbon))
machine on which I am unable to install programs and on which the `lsof` or `fuser` commands are not available.

I'm trying to remove an NFS dotfile on this machine but I keep getting the `Device or resource busy` error so I'd like to find out which process (I suspect it might be one I have previously started with `nohup`) still has a file descriptor to this file.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use `/proc/<PID>/fd`.

Example....we want to figure out which pid has `/var/log/audit/audit.log` open.  `fuser` tells us it's pid 255.

```
[root@instance-1 ~]# fuser /var/log/audit/audit.log
/var/log/audit/audit.log:   255
[root@instance-1 ~]#
```

So using a non `fuser` solution:

```
[root@instance-1 ~]# find /proc/*/fd -ls|grep /var/log/audit/audit.log
188652    0 l-wx------   1 root     root           64 Jul  1 06:22 /proc/255/fd/5 -> /var/log/audit/audit.log
[root@instance-1 ~]#
```

Comment: This method has the added advantage, that by default, it usually works with all users in Linux.